# How to run function with option code inside?

Tags: javascript, json

I have code like that :

```
<script>
function GetData(json)
{
.......

code1()
[or]
code2()
[or]
code3()

}
</script>
```

I want call `GetData` with any option (code1, code2, code3).

For example : How can call `GetData` with `code2()` while code1 and code3 are broken with option like :

```
<script>
code2();
document.write("<script src=\".....callback=GetData\"><\/script>");
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i cannot understand this question.

Comment: @mkoryak: thanks for your reply. you can see my question before for understand more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372724/display-more-style-for-only-function. please give me suggestion. thanks.

Comment: I am not good at any. So, everybody should not vote down my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your earlier question, and trying to understand what you need exactly, I believe there are two ways of solving your problem:

**1. Add another argument in your callback function**
[This page](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/#highlighter_616073) has a nice example of callbacks, but I believe you already understand that part.

In your code, you define the `function GetData(json)`. Maybe you should change that to

```
function GetData(json, callbackfunc) {
  ..
  // Here, instead of any logic for code1() or code2() etc, you just
  callbackfunc();
  ..
}
```

And you need to modify where you already call `GetData`, with the new function arguments.

**2. Use a global variable to define what you need**
If passing an additional argument is not possible for some reason, you may want to define a variable for your callback. Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var mynextcallback;

   function GetData(json) {
     ..
     mynextcallback();
     ..
   }       

 </script>
```

And in the part where you call `GetData`, you can do `mynextcallback = code1; GetData();`

Comment: Thanks your help. I am doing with your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry. Can you help me again for this. Actually, I cannot do this. Do with Jsfiddle here. Thanks @mavrosxristoforos. http://jsfiddle.net/ngnTq/2/

Comment: The fiddle that you posted does nothing - you should consider re-writing it, because I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear. You can see this image for clear more. https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-nNWV8IQo9E4/Ulz-VpVp65I/AAAAAAAAGrs/SoC9B8B8tXc/w790-h483-no/explain.png

Comment: Alright, so in one case it shows up with bullets because you are using a `<ul>` and in the other case it doesn't because you use `<div>` and `<p>`. I can't see any problem, or anything related to the original problem of this question. If it is a different problem, then you may want to open a new question.

Comment: ok. I did it. However, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KJSU5/

```
var code2 = function(){
    alert("This is code2");
};

function GetData()
{

    if(typeof code1 !== 'undefined'){
         code1();
         return;
    }

    if(typeof code2 !== 'undefined'){
         code2();
         return;
    }

    if(typeof code3 !== 'undefined'){
         code3();
         return;
    }
}
```